# Why does a cursor need to be sequential in pagination

Tags: pagination, database-cursor

I am building a cursor-based public API and read in various places that the pagination cursor should be sequential.

I use a UUID as PK and was thinking of returning the UUID PK as cursor. As a client can define filter parameters and sort-keys, I think that a UUID as cursor should be sufficient.

Are there more aspects that I am missing?

Appreciate any help

Edit: Maybe my confusion comes from a clients ability to specify sort-keys